# Function that returns a new list with values from original list that are divisible by a given number in the function parameters

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I need a function that takes an array, iterates over its values and for every one of its values that is divisible by 3 without a remainder, add it to a new array. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
def exampleFour(array,num):
    temp = []
    for i in array:
       if i % num == 0:
         temp.append(i)
    return temp

print(exampleFour([3,5,9,6,7,15,24],3))
```

However, when I run this it only returns [3]. Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: Your code returns `[3, 9, 6, 15, 24]` in my system.

Comment: ...this is almost certainly an indentation error; the code should work as it is presented here. check your indentations (hidden tabs?) and make sure the return statement is not inside the `for` loop.

Comment: There are no errors. I copied it and from here and it ran successfully, producing expected results.

Comment: Despite what is shown, you could have indented `return` statement, so it's falling inside `if` and returns immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is returning correct result for me, but you can do it easily.
Try this:

```
new_list = [i for i in array if i%num ==0]
```

Comment: Yes, @taurus05. I said that. just gave a better solution.

Comment: You can even try this : `new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x%num == 0, array))`